# Webgrid Pagination and Sorting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I have my webgrid in a partial page as follows. From the following page I updates my grid in a partial view, through an ajax call.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Book",FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "frmBGrid" }))
{

    <fieldset id="form">
    <div>
        <select id="BookType" name="BookType">

            @*<option value=""></option>*@

            <option selected="selected" value="0">View All</option>

            <option value="1">View New</option>

            <option value="2">View Published</option>

        </select>

    </div>

    <div id="BookGridid">
        @{
            @Html.Partial("_BookGridList", Model)
        }            

    </div>

</fieldset>
}
```

And My Ajax inside my drop down change, where I pass the selected drop-down value to the controller. And updates the grid based on the returned model.

```
var SelectedValue  = $('#BookType').val();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: href,
            dataType: "html",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ bookType: SelectedValue }),
            success: function (returndata) {

                $('#BookGridid').html(returndata);
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
            },
            error: function (arg, data, value) {
            }
        });
```

From my controller based on the parameter I will send back the Model list to bind to the webgrid.

However the problem is on pagination or sorting, I am unable to pass the selected drop down value. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored the Filtration Value in a session. Hence for Pagination also used that filtered value.